# PowerShell ForEach libreoffice conversion

Tags: powershell, libreoffice

I am trying to convert all rtf files to docx files under a specific folder and all sub folders. 
Converted files need to be at the same folder with the original files. Name of the converted files does not change.

This code converts the files but does not process subfolders. Only the top folder is being processed.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force  "C:test" -Filter *.rtf ) 
{
        &("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe") -headless -convert-to docx $file | Out-Null
}
```

Below code processes the subfolders but for some reason skips some files.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -Filter *.rtf -Recurse -Force | foreach-Object {
    set-location $_.directoryname
    &("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe") --convert-to docx $_.name
}
```

Lastly, libreoffice has an output directory option but I could not get it to work.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -Filter *.rtf) 
{
    &("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe") -headless -convert-to docx -outdir $FolderName $file | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$file` you could try to use the file name including the path ... `$file.FullName`

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\OneDrive - University of Houston\Anaconda3\JupyterFiles\audio\EarningsCalls\2020" -Filter *.rtf -Recurse -File| foreach-Object {
    set-location $_.directoryname
    write-host ($_)
    write-host ($_.FullName)
    write-host ($_.DirectoryName)
    &("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe") --convert-to docx -outdir $_.DirectoryName $_ | Out-Null  
}
```

Above code processes all the files and converts them.
Thank you everyone.